# Different Values for Animated.Value in RNI and Expo (Snack)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-animated

I get different results of Animated.Value in RNI and Expo Snack Application.

I created a new RNI App. Inside the App.js I added a new Animated.Value in a constructor, which I then console.log in the render method.

The console result is:

```
Animated Value:  AnimatedValue {_children: Array(0), _value: 0, _startingValue: 0, _offset: 0, _animation: null, …}
```

When i do the same in Expo Snack, the console result is:

```
Animated Value: 0
```

Why is this? How can I access the value in my RNI App? The pattern is used even in the react-native documentation. So I am a little surprised. Am I overseeing something?

Here is the Code auf die App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { left: new Animated.Value(0) };
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Animated Value: ', this.state.left);
    return (
      <Animated.View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mentioned in the [Expo Snack SDK](https://github.com/expo/snack-sdk#snack-sdk), the `flowTypes` for the error, log, and presence listeners have been defined as mentioned [here](https://github.com/expo/snack-sdk#listening-for-events)

```
// `console.log`, `console.warn`, `console.error`
export type ExpoDeviceLog = {
  device: ExpoDevice,
  method: 'log' | 'warn' | 'error',
  message: string,
  arguments: any, // the raw fields that were passed to the console.* call
};
```

Judging from the `flowTypes`, since they are expecting the message as a `String`, therefore it shows as a value rather than an object.
If you log the

```
    const animated = new Animated.Value(0)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(animated))
```

You'll get the same result.

Comment: thank you. I seemed to work, but when I try to assign the `JSON.stringify` Value to a style prop I receive the following error: `JSON value of type NSString cannot be converted to a YGValue. Did you forget the % or pt suffix?` I tried to convert by `toString()` but it does not work. any ideas?

Comment: What did you assign it to? To convert it to a number use `Number(string)`

Comment: oh thank you. thats it. 
I tried to assign it to marginBottom. due to the error message I was on the wrong track, thinking it should be a String value. but of course it must be a number value.